# AngularJS - Include calendar from bootstrap-like MetroUiCSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, calendar, datepicker

I would like to include in my project a calendar from Metro Ui CSS : http://metroui.org.ua/calendar.html

But i don't know how to activate the calendar.
I have included everything in the index.html (3 scripts), I have a template with the calendar div but how can I do the activation ?

In the link above, there are two ways to activate :

- with data-role, no result
- with jquery : $("component_id").calendar(); I don't know how to do that with AngularJS

Would anybody have an idea ?

Thanks

Edit :

Here are the includes from the index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/bower/metro-ui-css/docs/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/bower/metro-ui-css/docs/js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/bower/metro-ui-css/min/metro.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/bower/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/bower/angular-route/angular-route.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_lib/bower/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>

<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="common/CalendarDirective.js"></script>
...
```

And the error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Locale' of undefined
    at http://cloud.localhost.com/app/_lib/bower/metro-ui-css/min/metro.min.js:16:321

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Metro Ui CSS, you have to use jQuery. So, you should also include jQuery with your scripts.

And for make it work with AngularJS, use a directive like that:

```
app.directive('calendar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.calendar();
    }
  };
);
```

It will display your calendar. Also, you can add a controller to the directive to display it only when you click on the element:

```
app.directive('calendar', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller : function($scope, $element) {
        $scope.openCalendar = function(){
            $element.calendar();
        }
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    }
  };
});
```

And the html code :

```
<div class="calendar" calendar>
  <button ng-click="openCalendar()">open</button>
</div>
```

Hope this work.

As an alternative solution, you can use AngularUI components there is a [datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#datepicker) in it and style it.

**EDIT**

I've edited the code a little to have a button to click on it to display the calendar. Also, I've resolved your issue by including in this order :

1. `jquery.min.js`
2. `jquery.widget.min.js` - you can find it in the metro ui css archive at this location `Metro-UI-CSS-master\docs\js\jquery/jquery.widget.min.js`
3. `metro.min.js` - I didn't manage to make it work with just the files given for the calendar
4. AngularJS
5. The script with the directive

I've created a plunker here : http://plnkr.co/edit/oapSiyeIYCAYlpqAMAlt?p=preview

Comment: Thanks it's better but there is a error with metro ui css. TypeError: Cannot read property 'Locale' of undefined . I put a parameter "locale" but same result

Comment: Thanks for the example. Very strange because I have the same problem. See my edit

Comment: Maybe, you don't have the right metro.min.js version. Try to check the last one on their website. I don't know if with bower you took the last one.

Comment: i am checking with a simple code and another error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'days' of undefined at http://cloud.localhost.com/app/_lib/bower/metro-ui-css/min/metro.min.js:16:336

Comment: Well it works on Plunker with exactly the same code and library http://plnkr.co/edit/uGrS1RZQtJ5TXXoudimp?p=preview

Comment: So you have a problem with your code that you don't show. Maybe a conflict with another library ?